# How to stop Windows 10 feature "focus assist" from being enabled?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, windows-10-desktop

I'm using C# WinForms to create an overlay. The overlay needs to be the same size as (or bigger than) the current screen. However, it needs to not enable the "focus assist" feature.

I have tried using FormWindowState.Maximized and P/Invoke MoveWindow but as soon as the form becomes the same size as (or bigger than) the screen size then focus assist is enabled.

This is the code that I have so far:

**Overlay Form Contstructor**

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
    ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
    ControlStyles.UserPaint |
    ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
    ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)(GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE));
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(this.Handle, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);
this.TopMost = true;
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

**MoveWindow**

```
Screen screen = Screen.FromPoint(Cursor.Position);
MoveWindow(this.Handle, screen.Bounds.X, screen.Bounds.Y, screen.Bounds.Width, screen.Bounds.Height, true);
```

If there's any way to disable this feature, I have yet to find it. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no magic window option to override the feature, you'll have to consider overlaying only the active window instead of the entire screen.  If that window is maximized then the overlay will be maximized as well, but that follows the user's preference.  The only non-trivial thing you have to do is make the overlay follow the window when it gets moved.  Use System.Windows.Automation to get an event for that.

Comment: I have made overlays that do that in the past, I just wanted to know if there was a work around, or an API similar to the one that was available for Quiet Hours in previous Windows versions. At current, it doesn't seem possible without messing around with undocumented code, which I don't think is a good idea in a production codebase. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, there is no way to programatically turn on / off Focus Assist.

There are some [hacks](https://blog.quarkslab.com/playing-with-the-windows-notification-facility-wnf.html) out there, but I will not recommend using them.